# External navigation not working in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

Currently I'm trying to navigate outside of my application.

I've tried `window.location.href` `window.location.replace` etc

But when I do that it just appends my href to my domain "localhost:4200/"
Is it possible there's a setting somewhere that's preventing me from leaving the application programmatically?

I've also tried `router.navigateByUrl();`

This is all the information I can think of to provide but if you need more information I can try to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing something in the url passed to the `location.href`.

I've tried out this code and works fine :

```
window.location.href="http://www.google.it";
```

Comment: Haha I feel dumb, it was just being treated as a route because i didn't do anything to specify it was an external website via the url... hah

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **Jacopo Sciampi** that **window.location.href** should work.

However, you should probably check that your link starts with either **http://** or **https://** as it shows the browser that the link is external.

If this does not work, I would ask you to provide a source code to see the exact issue.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It was definitely the fact that I was missing the http/https. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help. Could you accept the answer that has worked for you?